# How to convert every two consecutive values of an array into a key/value pair?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
array('category_name:', 'c1', 'types:', 't1')
```

I want the alternate values of an array to be the values of an array:

```
array('category_name:' => 'c1', 'types:' => 't1')
```

Comment: You've asked nine questions and accepted none of them - do you know how to mark them as the chosen solution?

Comment: no i dont know, i am new to stack

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/379682/mayuri - where it says "9 Questions" open each question you've asked, and find the answer that you think is the best. Click the grey "tick" on the left and it becomes green. Do this for each question you've asked. Welcome to StackOverflow :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fold($a) {
    return $a 
        ? array(array_shift($a) => array_shift($a)) 
            + fold($a)
        : array();
}

print_r(fold(range('a','p' )));
```

~)

upd: a real-life version

```
function fold2($a) {
    $r = array();
    for($n = 1; $n < count($a); $n += 2)
        $r[$a[$n - 1]] = $a[$n];
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: this gives a range from alphabets, i want in only one array

Answer (score 2):

**You could try:** (untested)

```
$data = Array("category_name:","c1","types:","t1"); //your data goes here
for($i=0, $output = Array(), $max=sizeof($data); $i<$max; $i+=2) {
  $key = $data[$i];
  $value = $data[$i+1];
  $output[$key] = $value;
}
```

**Alternatively:** (untested)

```
$output = Array();
foreach($data as $key => $value):
  if($key % 2 > 0) { //every second item
    $index = $data[$key-1];
    $output[$index] = $value;
  }
endforeach;
```

Comment: $data = $trans; //trans in the array
for($i=0, $output = Array(), $max=sizeof($data); $i<$max; $i+=2) {
  $key = $data[$i];
  $value = $data[$i+1];
  $output[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($data);

Comment: That should work fine. Try `var_dump($output)` and see what it gives you.

Comment: array(3) { ["category_name:"]=> string(2) "c1" ["types:"]=> string(6) "types:" ["product"]=> string(12) "Basic search" }

Answer (score 1):

Here is another yet complex solution:

```
$keys = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(range(0, count($arr)-1, 2)));
$values = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(range(1, count($arr)-1, 2)));
$arr = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = your array;
$newArray['category_name:'] = $array[1];
$newArray['types:'] = $array[3];
```